# Finding a complementary linear subspace to a variety of correct dimension in $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $V\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety of dimension $d\geq 0$. I want to show that there exists a linear subspace $L\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ of codimension $d+1$ such that $L\cap V=\emptyset.$

**Edit**: I've figured it out, following Mohan's comment.

Comment: Can't you find (easily) a hyperplane $H$ with $\dim (H\cap V)<\dim V$ and do an easy induction?

Comment: Or a point not on $V$ and then induct (via linear projections) again.

Comment: @Mohan : Thanks, I've figured it out. Your hint was really helpful. I was thinking about it the wrong way the whole time.

Comment: Hello. How would you prove that $\dim(H\cap V) < \dim V$? I've tried by contradiction without success.